# printing error message to screen if '@' sign not detected

Tags: java

I have to exit the program using an if/else statement if the user's input of their email address does not include an '@' sign. Here is my code for this part:

```
//prompt user for their email address

System.out.print("\nPlease enter your email address: ");

//read user's input
emailAddress = keyboard.next();

//create username
String username = emailAddress.substring(0, emailAddress.indexOf('@'));

 //create username
atSign = emailAddress.lastIndexOf("@");
if(atSign >= 0){
    username = emailAddress.substring(0, atSign);
}
else{
    System.out.print("You've entered an invalid email address!");
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
        at Riccio_Lesson6.main(Riccio_Lesson6.java:51)
```

Comment: which one is line 51?

Comment: What does `lastIndexOf()` return when there is no matching substring?

Comment: @PM77-1 it returns -1 if not found

Comment: @PM77-1 return -1 if substring not found else a number from 0 to string.size

Comment: `String username = emailAddress.substring(0, emailAddress.indexOf('@'));` Don't run this code until after you have made sure the string has the `@` symbol.

Comment: @Sedrick but then won't the second 'create username' part not work because the variable username is in it, and if i put that part of the code after, it will say variable username has not been initialized

Comment: @Doc it is a comment line

Comment: I would start with something like `if(emailAddress.contains("@"){ //Set username and other stuff here!}else{//Due your current error print out}`.

Comment: @Sedrick we haven't learned the contains method in class so i wouldn't be able to use it. is there another way?

Comment: @Doc answer below.

Comment: Take a look at my answer for if it contains character. @JuliaRiccio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String username = emailAddress.substring(0, emailAddress.indexOf('@'));//this will throw exception
```

What to do?

Create `username` before and set it to either `null` or an empty string. Then check if the symbol is present or not.

```
 String username = null;
 // or String username = "";

     //create username 
 atSign = emailAddress.lastIndexOf("@"); 
  if(atSign >= 0){ 
    username = emailAddress.substring(0, atSign);
 } 
 else{ 
     System.out.print("You've entered an invalid email address!");
     System.out.println("Goodbye!");


   // use return to stop code here if in a method(better choice) or
   // if in the main() uncomment the code below
   // System.exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: this works, thank you!! the rest of the program still runs after though, is there any way to completely stop it?

Comment: @Julia Riccio This is what you're looking for, in response to your last comment.

Comment: @JuliaRiccio If you want to completely stop the code. Use `System.exit(0)`; See the updated answer.

Comment: @Doc @JuliaRiccio Don't use `System.exit(0)` (unless maybe you're in `main`). It makes the code path untestable. Better options are: structuring the code so that a `return` can be used, or throwing an exception.

Comment: @JuliaRiccio if that was useful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with your line:

```
String username = emailAddress.substring(0,emailAddress.indexOf('@'));
```

If the email address does not contain an "@" then `emailAddress.indexOf('@')` returns `-1`, meaning you're trying to call `emailAddress.substring(0, -1)`.

-1 is not a valid index, which causes the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: how do i get it to be if the email address does not contain an "@" then the exit message appears using the if/else statement?